# IIS7 - no response from server on request with DELETE verb

Tags: iis-7, request, windows-server-2008, http-delete, http-verbs

I have a Windows 2008 Server running the default IIS 7.0. I have an http handler where GET, POST, and PUT are working fine, but whenever I issue a DELETE request, there is nothing coming back from the server at all.

I'm using Fiddler to issue the request (which works great on my development Windows 7 machine). I have disabled WebDav, etc., which by the way should have given me some kind of error response anyway. In this case there's nothing. I've tried to enable tracing on the server and don't see anything there either.

I have tried to issue the DELETE web requests on other pages on the server as well, including non-existing ones, but there's never any respone. Maybe something on the server is "eating" the request before it gets to IIS?

To test this last question, I installed Fiddler on the server itself and posted the DELETE request from within the server. This actually worked!!! So, what's stopping the external request then?

Comment: It looks like it's a firewall issue. I'm able to make the DELETE request when I'm using https instead of http.

Comment: My ISP confirmed their firewall was blocking the DELETE request and have fixed the issue now.